# "Maximum-value" not increasing when "initial.maxvalue" is set and "Maximum-value column" name is different from "id"

Tags: apache-nifi

when "Maximum-value column" name is "id" there is no problem, when i add "`initial.maxvalue.id`" property in "`QueryDatabaseTable`" processor, it works well and [image: maxvalue] is increasing by every running.

but...

when the "Maximum-value column" name is different from "id" (such as "tweet_id"), after initial processor working, only given "`initial.maxvalue.id`" is saves and that repeating just [image: same value] for every run.

what i must to do? i need to query a database and fetch data that id greater than X (initial.maxvalue) not from beginning!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what you have tried?

Comment: try this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12890291/subquery.csv  i connect to mariaDB database using jdbc, and query this table to return records greater than X by initial.maxvalue.tweet_id . at first use this works well, but i need this processor scheduled and for next run this problem is happening and maxvalue on view state not changing.
i using this processor on other tables and there is not any problem, but this different!
is it probable that relates to "Use Avro Logical Types" or "Default Decimal Precision" or "Default Decimal Scale"? because of length of tweet_id?